# Christoffel Symbol Not Disappearing

Tags: differential-geometry

If I am given a vector field $\vec{A}(x,y) = x^2 \hat{e}_1 + y^2 \hat{e}_2 = (A^x,A^y)$, I'd like to calculate it's covariant derivative in the $r$ direction after expressing the vector field in polar coordinates in a polar basis. The solution is given [here](http://books.google.com.vn/books?id=IQWLMHc0FaIC&pg=PA172&dq=%22find%20the%20covariant%20derivative%20of%20the%20vector%20field%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=AiHoUYKDH4SOO5LPgZAJ&ved=0CCsQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22find%20the%20covariant%20derivative%20of%20the%20vector%20field%22&f=false), but I just want to understand what's going on.

Thus to find the components of a contravariant vector expressed in one (Cartesian) $\{\hat{e}_r,\hat{e}_{\theta}\}$ basis in terms of another (polar) $\{\hat{e}_r,\hat{e}_{\theta}\}$ basis I use the result $(\bar{T}^i) = (\tfrac{\partial \bar{x}^i}{\partial x^j}T^j)$ to find

$$\vec{A} = (A^x,A^y) = (x^2,y^2) = (\tfrac{d r}{\partial x}x(r,\theta ) +
   \tfrac{\partial r}{\partial y} y(r, \theta ),\tfrac{d \theta
   }{\partial x} x(r,\theta ) + \tfrac{\partial \theta}{\partial y}y(r,
   \theta ) ) = (r^2(\cos^3(\theta ) +
   \sin^3(\theta)),r\sin(\theta)\cos(\theta)(\sin(\theta)-\cos(\theta))) = (A^r,A^\theta).$$

Also the bases are found using:

$$ \vec{r}(x,y)_{Euc} = x \hat{e}_x + y \hat{e}_y$$
$$ \vec{r}(r,\theta)_{Euc} = r\cos(\theta) \vec{e}_r + r\sin(\theta)e_{\theta}$$
$$\hat{e}_r = \tfrac{\tfrac{\partial \vec{r_{Euc}}}{\partial r}}{||\tfrac{\partial \vec{r_{Euc}}}{\partial r}||} = \cos(\theta) \hat{e}_x + \sin(\theta) \hat{e}_y$$
$$\hat{e}_r = \tfrac{\tfrac{\partial \vec{r_{Euc}}}{\partial \theta}}{||\tfrac{\partial \vec{r_{Euc}}}{\partial \theta}||} = - \sin(\theta) \hat{e}_x + \cos(\theta) \hat{e}_y$$
$$\hat{e}_x = \cos(\theta)\hat{e}_r - \sin(\theta)\hat{e}_\theta$$
$$\hat{e}_y = \sin(\theta)\hat{e}_r + \cos(\theta)\hat{e}_\theta$$

Then using the differential $d\vec{A}$:

$$d\vec{A} = \tfrac{\partial \vec{A}}{\partial x}dx + \tfrac{\partial \vec{A}}{\partial y}dy = \tfrac{\partial \vec{A}}{\partial r}dr + \tfrac{\partial \vec{A}}{\partial \theta}d \theta$$
$$d\vec{A}_{Euc} = d(A^x \hat{e}_x + A^y \hat{e}_y) = dA^x \hat{e}_x + dA^y \hat{e}_y + A^x d \hat{e}_x + A^y d \hat{e}_y $$
$$d\vec{A}_{Pol} = d(A^r \hat{e}_r + A^\theta \hat{e}_\theta) = dA^r \hat{e}_r + dA^\theta \hat{e}_\theta + A^r d \hat{e}_r + A^\theta d \hat{e}_\theta$$

to derive the covariant derivative we have

$$\tfrac{\partial \vec{A}_{Euc}}{\partial x} = \tfrac{\partial A^x}{\partial x} \hat{e}_x + \tfrac{ \partial A^y}{\partial x} \hat{e}_y + A^x \tfrac{\partial \hat{e}_x}{\partial x} + A^y \tfrac{\partial \hat{e}_y}{\partial x} = 2x\hat{e}_x$$
$$\tfrac{\partial \vec{A}_{Pol}}{\partial r} = \tfrac{\partial A^r}{\partial r} \hat{e}_r + \tfrac{\partial A^\theta}{\partial r} \hat{e}_\theta + A^r \tfrac{\partial \hat{e}_r}{\partial r} + A^\theta \tfrac{\partial \hat{e}_\theta}{\partial r}$$

Now, according to what I've written above I should get that $\tfrac{\partial \hat{e}_r}{\partial r} = 0$ & $\tfrac{\partial \hat{e}_\theta}{\partial r} = 0$, so that

$$\tfrac{\partial \vec{A}_{Pol}}{\partial r} = (2r(\cos^3(\theta ) +
   \sin^3(\theta)),\sin(\theta)\cos(\theta)(\sin(\theta)-\cos(\theta)))  $$

But apparently, if I'm reading the page I linked to above correctly, the answer is:

$$\tfrac{\partial \vec{A}_{Pol}}{\partial r} = (2r(\cos^3(\theta ) +
   \sin^3(\theta)),2\sin(\theta)\cos(\theta)(\sin(\theta)-\cos(\theta)))$$

which results from [a term remaining when you expand it out in terms of a Christoffel symbol](http://books.google.com.vn/books?id=FesDylvUy00C&pg=PA289&dq=%22find%20the%20covariant%20derivative%20of%20the%20vector%20field%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=j0YwUsunKOnn7AbP9oHQDQ&ved=0CDcQuwUwAQ#v=onepage&q=%22find%20the%20covariant%20derivative%20of%20the%20vector%20field%22&f=false), but from what I've written there should be no Christoffel symbols, what have I done wrong?

Comment: You unitised the basis vectors – but Christoffel symbols are supposed to be used with _coordinate_ basis vectors, which in this case are non-unital.